How can I find fasta sequences for gp120 and gp41 for different HIV subtypes?
I need to extract the Env gp120 and gp41 subsequences for the following HIV-1 strains: A, B, C, D, N, and O.
I've been successfully using UniProt for env and tat sequences, but I'm having trouble finding gp120 sequences. When I search for "hiv-1 gp120," the results mostly suggest gp160, which is expected. However, when I select any of these suggestions and click through to the GenBank sequence, it leads me to whole genome sequences (like https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/K02013) without specific annotations for gp120 or gp41.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to find the precise gp120 and gp41 sequences for these strains? Thanks!
